# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError with fb_auth.exchange_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fb-graph

In Production I am getting the following error while running

```
fb_auth.exchange_token! access_token
```

but it was running before, I got the error

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A: sslv3 
alert handshake failure
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this
https://github.com/nov/fb_graph/issues/372

Not a fb-graph or httpclient error?
Try this
http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html